# Rebuild FutureBuilder from another widget

Tags: flutter, setstate, countdowntimer, flutter-futurebuilder

Right now, I am using a FutureBuilder to build a list of activities. But the activities have a timer, using CountdownTimerController, which runs down to 0. I want to change the list and update the list onEnd of the timer. But the timer widget is on a different file overall. How could I do the needful?

```
                          FutureBuilder(
                                        future: fetchUserActivities(),
                                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                              ConnectionState.done) {
                                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                              return Center(
                                                .....
```

What should I change in this or add in `OnEnd` function of the timer to update the list?

Answer (score 0):

you should embed your list in an other FutureBuilder inside the the one you use to fetch activities. Or put each list in a Statefull widget and call a setState by the end of your timer.
According to your comment, an easy way will be using a state management package like RiverPod, put your timer in a ChangeNotifier and use Consumer widget in your other page.

Comment: The FutureBuilder is inside a Stateful widget itself, but the problem arises when I have my timer.dart file running the timer. And I want to rebuild this list when it becomes 0 on another page and I can't figure out how should I do the rebuilding.